# How can save rgba image on pyplot?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, rgba

I can show rgba image using `pyplot.imshow(image,alpha=0.8)`.

I tried to save image using `pyplot.savefig()`, but image included padding is saved.

I want to save only image which not have padding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544130/saving-an-imshow-like-image-while-preserving-resolution

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for reply. i will refer your link.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use: `pyplot.savefig()` instead of pyplot.saveconfig()?
if yes, then you can use `bbox_inches='tight'` to remove or reduce margins and padding around the image:
solution one:
`pyplot.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: .Thank you for reply. Your answer very nice!! i have typo, and i edited saveconfig() to savefig().i want to vote, but i cant. becuz not enough my point...