# Create a Colored Image from a Gray Image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am new here and I need some help.

I have a gray image, and I need to colour it using Python.

This is the kind of images I have:
[image]

And I need to transform it to be like the images that can be plot by using matplotlib ColorMap "CMRmap" like this one and save it:

[image]

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately we are not a code writing service, and we ask, at the minimum, that you show some code for what you've tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Comment: you don't need to transform the image, just display it with the correct colormap

Comment: Use matplotlib.pyplot to display your image. It will color code automatically or you can select other color tables or create your own.

Comment: Actually i need to save the images, i already know how to display it this way.

Comment: This should help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546410/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've figured out the colormap part, but not the saving. Building on Shawn's answer, if you want to save the figure, make a call to `plt.savefig()` instead of `plt.show()`. Then pass the path you want to save it to as an argument.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread(r"path\to\img", 0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='CMRmap')
plt.savefig("\path\to\output\file")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Wassim - if it solves your problem, then could you mark it as the accepted solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dominic, i just as add [solved] to the title or is there another way to do so ?

Comment: There should be a greyed-out tick under the up/downvote buttons. If you click it to accept the solution it goes green!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Miki's comment, you simply need to use a colormap. The colored image shows the CMRmap colormap.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread(r"path\to\img", 0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='CMRmap')
plt.plot()
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Output:

[image]

Matplotlib lists all the colormaps [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html)

Edit: updated answer with OP's clarification.

Comment: Thank you, but i already did that, the problem is how to save the image. Sorry i wasn't clear enough in my question.